# Como guardar ângulos de desenhos c#

Tags: c#

No meu jogo é suposto os utilizadores desenharem figuras que eu mostro, eu quero guardar os ângulos dos desenhos para comparar com os dados que eu já tenho guardados numa base de dados e ver se o que o utilizador desenhou é aceitável.

A partir do momento em que o utilizador começa a desenhar a figura não pode levantar o dedo do botão do rato, caso contrário perde, se a figura não estiver concluída ou não corresponder a nada do que se encontra na base de dados
Eu vou usar o método `system.drawing`

Comment: O que ocorre se o utilizador desenhar um círculo?

Comment: A pergunta me pareceu muito ampla. Poderia ser mais especifico? Demonstre melhor o que pretende e onde esta seu problema.

Comment: Como o usuário entra com o desenho? É através de um pincel ou através de um conjunto de pontos pegues a cada clique?

Comment: @Renan pois eu já pensei nesse problema e também não sei como hei de resolver, mas para o caso de eu não saber de momento simplesmente não incluo no jogo pois eu sou quem dá as figuras, mas isso é um ponto a considerar.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim vou usar Pen, a minha ideia é passar aleatoriamente umas figuras selecionadas por mim numa zona específica do ecrã  e o utilizador tenta fazer igual, imaginemos que é um quadrado, caso eles comecem pela linha da base e depois passem para as laterais, eu penso que é nesse momento em que o X e/ou o Y teem uma mudança dramática no valor que eu devo marcar um ponto, e quando eu tiver 2 ou 3 (incluindo o ponto que eu marco mal a pessoa carregue no rato para começar a desenhar) calculo o ângulo